# Track Google Analytics conversions from domain to subdomain

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I'd like to track the conversion rate of my site using Google Analytics across multiple subdomains.

The scenario:

A: www.site.com <- where sessions begin.

B: app.site.com <- where sign up starts.

A conversion for www.site.com is a session moving to app.site.com.

Currently conversions on site.com look like drop offs.

I've already set up two views to separate A and B.

Side note: B is ignoring referrals from A.

I've set up conversion tracking on B.

My question is: how do I track the conversion of site.com sessions travelling to app.site.com using Google's Universal Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)? If so this happens automatically.

The main way people screw it up is by not setting `cookieDomain` to `'auto'`, which, if you use the default snippet, should already be the case:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

Without seeing your implementation, it's impossible to know why yours isn't working, but just know this *does* work out of the box with no special configuration.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [developer site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain), Universal Analytics does not require further customisation to the _ga cookie. Use the default analytics.js code snippet to track between your domain and subdomain. Make sure to use the javascript code in both websites.

If you require that a visit to app.site.com is considered a conversion in site.com, then you need to attach an event to the link in site.com that points to the app.site.com and setup a goal for that event.

Have a read to [this article](http://moz.com/blog/cross-domain-subdomain-tracking-in-google-analytics), hope that helps.

Cheers